# Merge only recurring duplicate objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, merge

Given an array as

```
[
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1}
]
```

I will like to merge it in such a way that if they are recurring, then we merge and sum up the `span` property. So, the expected output is

```
[
    {name: 'John', span: 2},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 3}
]
```

Can anyone suggest a suitable way to do this? The best I could come up with was

```
var data = [
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1}
];
var result = [];

var count = 0;
while (count <= data.length) {
    var datum = data[count];
    var isFound = false;

    do {
        var nextCount = data[++count];

        if (!nextCount) {
            break;
        }

        if (nextCount.name === datum.name) {
            datum.span += 1;
            isFound = true;
        } else {
            isFound = false;
        }
    } while(isFound);   

    result.push(datum);
}

console.log(result);
```

This works, save for an `undefined` which is placed at the end (don't know why). Can anyone suggest a more effective and readable way to do this?

Comment: Your last undefined is there because your count goes to `<= data.length`. Remember that array starts at 0 and if it has 7 elements you need to go until index 6, which means strict less than `count < data.length`. This is just explanation for your `undefined` case, there are still more effective ways to write this but let's leave that to proper answers.

Comment: @MiroslavSaracevic. Thanks. I tried by checking `count < data.length`, it took out the `undefined`. Thanks for the explanation as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter and update the object while checking the last object.

This solution mutates the original array.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'John', span: 1 }, { name: 'John', span: 1 }, { name: 'Peter', span: 1 }, { name: 'John', span: 1 }, { name: 'Peter', span: 1 }, { name: 'Peter', span: 1 }, { name: 'Peter', span: 1 }],
    result = array.filter((last => o => {
        if (!last || last.name !== o.name) {
            last = o;
            return true;
        }
        last.span += o.span;
    })());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var data = [
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'John', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
    {name: 'Peter', span: 1}
];

function groupSpans(data) {
    const result = [];
    let current;
    let currentKey;
    data.forEach((datum) => {
        if(datum.name !== currentKey) {
            currentKey = datum.name;
            current = {... datum};
            result.push(current);
            return;
        }
        current.span++;
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(groupSpans(data));
```

-->

```
~/Desktop $ node so50677991.js
[ { name: 'John', span: 2 },
  { name: 'Peter', span: 1 },
  { name: 'John', span: 1 },
  { name: 'Peter', span: 3 } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution

```
const arr = [
  {name: 'John', span: 1},
  {name: 'John', span: 1},
  {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
  {name: 'John', span: 1},
  {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
  {name: 'Peter', span: 1},
  {name: 'Peter', span: 1}
]

const parsed = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(acc[acc.length - 1] && acc[acc.length - 1].name == item.name) {
    acc[acc.length - 1].span++
  } else {
    acc.push(item)
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(parsed)
```